# Trying to get Affectiva to Run on Node.js with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, image-processing, phantomjs

Affectiva has [a JavaScript SDK for the web](https://knowledge.affectiva.com/v4.0.0/docs/getting-started-with-the-emotion-sdk-for-javascript), but no module for Node.js.  I'm trying to make them work together with a headless browser, like PhantomJS. (Note: there is [a third-party Affectiva module on npm](https://github.com/dggriffin/affrestivajs), but that is for [their REST API](https://knowledge.affectiva.com/v4.0.0/docs/media-processing-api), not the SDK I want to use.)

I've set up a test page in such a way that I can test the same code in both PhantomJS and Chrome 67. But I'm running into an error on the PhantomJS side that I can't seem to debug. *Is the answer as simple as* **"PhantomJS doesn't have full support for the Image, ImageData, or Uint8ClampedArray classes?"**  The only clues that I've been able to find are that Object.keys() gives different results for these classes between Chrome & PhantomJS. Perhaps Affectiva's SDK is relying on Object.keys() and the error is a result of that?

Thanks in advance for any helpful insights.

*Client-side:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <canvas id='canvas' width='640' height='800'></canvas>

  <script src='https://download.affectiva.com/js/3.2/affdex.js'></script>

  <script>

    function startProcessing() {
      console.log('initialized');
      if (typeof window.callPhantom === 'function') {
        window.callPhantom('initialized');
      }
    }

    function saveResults(faces, image, timestamp) {
      console.log('timestamp:', timestamp);
      if (typeof window.callPhantom === 'function') {
        window.callPhantom(faces);
      }
    }

    function catchError(image, timestamp, err_detail) {
      if (typeof window.callPhantom === 'function') {
        window.callPhantom({error: err_detail});
      }
    }

    function processFrame(imgUrl) {

      var img = new Image();   // Create new img element
      img.addEventListener('load', function() {
        console.log('img:', img);
        // In Chrome:      img: object <img crossorigin scr="https://example.com/face.jpg">
        // In PhantomJS:   img: [object HTMLImageElement]

        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        // Get imageData object.
        var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 640, 800);
        console.log('imageData:', typeof(imageData), imageData, Object.keys(imageData));
        // In Chrome:      imageData: object ImageData{data: Uint8ClampedArray(2048000), width: 640, height: 800} ["data"]
        // In PhantomJS:   imageData: object [object ImageData] height,width,data

        // Remove prototype attributes that PhantomJS includes in Object.keys() (DOESN'T HELP)
        delete imageData.data.length;
        delete imageData.data.byteOffset;
        delete imageData.data.byteLength;
        delete imageData.data.buffer;
        var uint8caKeys = Object.keys(imageData.data).sort().reverse();

        console.log('imageData.data:', typeof(imageData.data), imageData.data, uint8caKeys.length, uint8caKeys.slice(0,6), imageData.data[1985161]);
        // In Chrome:      imageData.data: object Uint8ClampedArray(2048000) [42, 36, 25, 255...] 2048000 ["999999", "999998", "999997", "999996", "999995", "999994"]                  232
        // In PhantomJS:   imageData.data: object [object Uint8ClampedArray]                      2048004 length,byteOffset,byteLength,buffer,999999,999998,999997,999996,999995,999994 230
        // Extra whitespace added by me

        //Process the frame
        detector.process(imageData, 0);
        // In Chrome:    saveResults() triggered with expected data
        // In PhantomJS: catchError() triggered with CALLBACK: "worker code reported an exceptionTypeError: Cannot convert \"undefined\" to int"

      }, false);
      img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '');
      img.src = imgUrl;

    }

    var aCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = aCanvas.getContext('2d');
    var detector = new affdex.PhotoDetector(affdex.FaceDetectorMode.LARGE_FACES);
    detector.detectAllEmotions();
    detector.detectAllAppearance();
    detector.addEventListener('onInitializeSuccess',   startProcessing);
    detector.addEventListener('onInitializeFailure',   catchError);
    detector.addEventListener('onImageResultsSuccess', saveResults);
    detector.addEventListener('onImageResultsFailure', catchError);
    detector.start();

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

*Server-side:*

```
const instance = await phantom.create();
const page = await instance.createPage();
await page.on('onResourceRequested', (requestData) => {
  console.info('Requesting', requestData.url);
  // PhantomJS seems to be downloading all the correct scripts
});

page.on('onConsoleMessage', msg => {
  console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg);
});

page.on('onCallback', data => {
  console.log('CALLBACK: ' + JSON.stringify(data));

  if (data==='initialized') {

    page.evaluate(function(imgUrl){
      processFrame(imgUrl);
    }, 'https://example.com/face.jpg');

  }
});

const openStatus = await page.open('http://localhost:1337/affectiva-test');
if (openStatus==='success') {
  exits.success();
} else {
  exits.error(openStatus);
}
```

Comment: Although I'd like to find a pure JavaScript solution, the best option, in the end, might be for my node.js app to run Affectiva's C++ SDK through through the OS... https://knowledge.affectiva.com/v4.0.0/docs/getting-started-with-the-affectiva-sdk-for-linux

Comment: PhantomJS is based on a *very* old Webkit engine, so all sorts of things could not work. Can you migrate to [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/)? It's native node module being developed by Google and the latest Chromium underneath. With async/await it's a delight writing scripts for it.

Comment: I'll try puppeteer, thanks.

Comment: @Vaviloff , do you happen to know if puppeteer has an event listener to PhantomJS' `onCallback` ? I see that `page.on('console', cb);` is an option, but that makes it difficult to pass anything other than text from the client to the node app...

Comment: I don't think there's a direct analog for that; you can subscribe to custom events: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/examples/custom-event.js and then generate them in page code. `anything other than text` - actually it has always been the case, even with PhantomJS. Only simple serializable objects can be passed both ways.

Comment: Maybe I should listen for console logging, then check a client-side global variable with `page.evaluate()`?

Comment: Sure you could do that, but maybe a simpler approach (not sure what exactly the use case is) would be to pass data with `XHR` POST requests from the `page` to your own server?

Comment: Yeah, I'm considering that too.  I'll need to pass data for a few events per second, though and I was guessing that routing it through Puppeteer event listeners would be faster than XHR.  Is it worth testing or is your impression that XHR would be faster? I suppose the benefit of XHR is that I can buffer the data for a while and send it in chunks (which would be a problem with console text).

Comment: Very valid points! But the only way to know what would run better is to try and check both solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Finding an alternative headless browser seems to be the answer.  As @Vaviloff suggested, I switched to [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/). The biggest change is that data can't be passed from the client page back to the node.js app quite so simply as `window.callPhantom()`.  In this example, I'm sending stringified-objects through with `console.log()`.  @Vaviloff suggested having the client page make an AJAX call back to the server instead. It's not yet clear to me which will perform better.

*Client-side:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <canvas id='canvas' width='640' height='800'></canvas>
  <script src='https://download.affectiva.com/js/3.2/affdex.js'></script>

  <script>

    function startProcessing() {
      console.log('initialized');
    }

    function saveResults(faces, image, timestamp) {
      delete faces[0].emojis;
      console.log('result:', JSON.stringify(faces[0]));
    }

    function catchError(image, timestamp, err_detail) {
      console.log(err_detail);
    }

    function processFrame(imgUrl, timestamp) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.addEventListener('load', function() {
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 640, 800);
        detector.process(imageData, timestamp);

      }, false);
      img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '');
      img.src = imgUrl;
    }

    console.log('initializing');
    var aCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = aCanvas.getContext('2d');
    var detector = new affdex.PhotoDetector(affdex.FaceDetectorMode.LARGE_FACES);
    detector.detectAllEmotions();
    detector.detectAllAppearance();
    detector.addEventListener('onInitializeSuccess',   startProcessing);
    detector.addEventListener('onInitializeFailure',   catchError);
    detector.addEventListener('onImageResultsSuccess', saveResults);
    detector.addEventListener('onImageResultsFailure', catchError);
    detector.start();

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

*Server-side:*

```
// If you are analyzing video (instead of images), avoid the default, bundled Chromium browser, since it doesn't support MP4
// const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: '/path/to/Chrome'});

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();

page.on('console', msg => {
  if (msg.text()==='initialized') {
    page.evaluate(
      (imgUrl, timestamp) => processFrame(imgUrl, timestamp),
      'https://example.com/face.jpg',
       0
    );
  }
  console.log('PAGE LOG:', msg.text());
});
await page.goto('http://localhost:1337/affectiva-test');

exits.success();
```

Comment: I haven't scaled it properly yet to compare this with XHR, but right now it seems fast enough to be a reasonable option.  I'll add to the post later.